# how I can activate ReCAPTCHA

Tags: magento2, captcha

Though we can activate captcha in our Magento 2 store but being recaptcha offers more security would like to know How can I install and enable reCAPTCHA in my Magento 2 Store.

Comment: Check https://ranasohel.me/2016/07/06/how-to-integrate-recaptcha-in-magento-2-contact-page/

Comment: https://magecomp.com/magento-2-google-recaptcha.html

Comment: Invisible https://magecomp.com/magento-2-google-invisible-recaptcha.html

Answer (score 2):

The best - in my opinion - module for Magento 2, giving you fully-configurable ReCaptcha with invisible mode to avoid conversion loss is **MageSpecialist** one available for free on GitHub: https://github.com/magespecialist/m2-MSP_ReCaptcha

To install it, you just need to:

```
composer require msp/recaptcha
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

Then generate public and secret key at Google: https://www.google.com/recaptcha/admin and put it in an Admin Panel (Stores / Configuration / Security Suite / Google reCaptcha)

Comment: not working in  mobile and chrome...only working in firefox..chrome sometimes it visible

Comment: I am using magento 2.3.2 and captcha V3

Answer (score 1):

Let's try [Google Invisible reCaptcha for Magento 2](https://amasty.com/google-invisible-recaptcha-for-magento-2.html) its worked for me, it's FREE and easy to use on multiple forms...

Hope it helps...

Comment: Hi Riyas... It is not free. It is the cost for $69

Comment: It used to be free, but not anymore

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use this https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-google-recaptcha/
 It is free and included many features.

Step 1 : Create account on google : https://www.google.com/recaptcha/
here you can get 2 keys. One is sitekey and other is secretkey. Select Invisible key.  Fill form like this given image. 
[image]

Step 2 : Download extension from mageplaza from this url : https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-google-recaptcha/

Step 3 : Upload it as given instruction on its doc file. (It is simple. Simply you have to upload app folder to your magento website)

Step 4 : Clean magento catch and activate extention. Go to Store -> Configuration -> Mageplaza Extensions -> Google Recaptcha

General -> Enable -> Yes

Now Insert those 2 keys in General -> Invisible section.

Frontend Configuration -> Enable -> Yes

Now select which pages have captcha.  Select the form.

Now save it. Flush catch and check your pages.